# PLINQO Not Naming Entities Correctly

Tags: plinqo

I have my CSP file set up to use TableNaming and EntityNaming as Singular:

```
 <TableNaming>Singular</TableNaming>
 <EntityNaming>Singular</EntityNaming>
```

Yet the generated entities are plural.

For instance, I have a table called Companies. The generated name is "Companies" I expected "Company" (like LinqToSql did -- I am upgrading a project.)

I have a table named EntityStorageItems (no relation to these entities.) The generated name is "EntityStorageItems" I expected the entity name to be "EntityStorageItem"

IOW, it is creating plural names. And I need them to be singular (to work with existing code.)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you change your CSP after your DBML had been generated? I *think* (maybe wrong) these keys only take effect on additions to the model.

Comment: I deleted / recreated all the generated files multiple times (including the DBML.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in [PLINQO 5.0](http://community.codesmithtools.com/blogs/announcements/archive/2010/06/09/plinqo-5-0-an-orm-for-2010.aspx).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski